# Facebook Graph API: Get user's profile url?

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-graph-api

The Facebook Graph API lists a 'link' parameter in its [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user), which is the user's profile url. Mine is http://www.facebook.com/adambossy.

This is not listed as one of the available [Extended Permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions), so, presumably, it's available without asking. I believe it's publicly available as Google results would reveal this.

However, pinging the API with a proper access token using OAuth doesn't yield the link parameter in the return value. It works for some friend's accounts, but not all, and I don't see any privacy settings pertaining to this.

Why is the 'link' parameter not being returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely it's your privacy settings. The example on the graph API shows a bunch more information being returned: https://graph.facebook.com/arjun My profile data returned looks just like yours and I have my privacy settings all set to "Only Friends" or "None" if I can.